# Runnable instanceof Future<?>?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, future, runnable

I was reading some javadoc and I came across [this example from `ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute(...)` javadocs:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute%28java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Throwable%29)

```
class ExtendedExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
   // ...
   protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
     super.afterExecute(r, t);
     if (t == null && r instanceof Future<?>) {
       try {
         Object result = ((Future<?>) r).get();
       } catch (CancellationException ce) {
           t = ce;
       } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
           t = ee.getCause();
       } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
           Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // ignore/reset
       }
     }
     if (t != null)
       System.out.println(t);
   }
 }
```

Can anybody explain me how the code can pass the first if. I mean how `r` can be instanceof `Future<?>`?

Comment: Can you explain why you think that's *not* possible?

Comment: Well, perhaps `r` is a [RunnableFuture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RunnableFuture.html).

Comment: `public class Foo implements Runnable, Future<Bar> { ... }`

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anybody explain me how the code can pass the first if. I mean how r can be instanceof Future?

You are correct to be confused.  It is somewhat strange code that passes in a `Runnable` and then tries to cast it to a `Future` which doesn't extend `Runnable`.  It's not a pattern you see often.  This is in the javadocs for [`ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute(...)` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Throwable)) and after looking at the code, the `r` argument to the method is the task that has finished.

I think the code would be a lot more clean if it was a `FutureTask` instead of a `Future`.  `FutureTask` is even mentioned right above the sample code in the javadocs:

> When actions are enclosed in tasks (such as {@link FutureTask})...

`FutureTask` implements `RunnableFuture` which is both a `Runnable` and a `Future` so the code works but using `FutureTask` would be less confusing.

Comment: `FutureTask` is one of implementation that belongs both to `Runnable` and `Future`. There might be alternative set of objects that both part of `Runnable` and `Future` but still out of `FutureTask` objects. I think javadoc is more precise. If you'll use `FutureTask` you may miss some implementation that might be introduced by 3rd party frameworks or even by you.

Answer (score 0):

'?' is a type argument, not a type parameter!